# A shorter/cleaner way to add item to beginning of array, while also removing the last?

Tags: javascript

I added pagination to a project I'm working on, which uses React and Redux.

When I create a new item, I want it appended to the current list, while also removing the last item in the list; as each page has a limit to how many items to display.

The solution I came up with is something like this.

Basically, I want to add `1` to the array, but also remove `3`; so the new array will be `[1,2]`.

EDIT: sorry, but if this was a redux reducer, where I have to do everything in one line, how would I accomplish that?

```
const add = 1;
const state = [2,3];

const update = [add, ...state.filter((num, idx) =>{
  return idx !== state.length - 1
})]

reducer sample:

return {
   ...state,
   items: [add, ...state.filter((num, idx) =>{
      return idx !== state.length - 1
    })]
}
```

I might be overthinking it, and I have a feeling there is a much much cleaner way to write this..

What I also don't like is that I'm not even using the first argument in filter. It's just there so I can access the index..

Comment: `state.unshift(1); state.pop(); console.log(state);`

Comment: Just to clear that up: You don't have to do everything in one line in a redux reducer. Such a restriction does not exist.
Also, be sure to check out the official redux toolkit, which will allow you to write your code mutable and make stuff like this a lot easier: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/

Comment: thank you much appreciated. I was under the impression this entire time that it has to be in one line. Will read more into the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slice()`. The negative ending index works backwards from end of array

```js
const add = 1;
const state = [2,3]

const res = [add, ...state.slice(0,-1)]
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last element of an array use array pop method and to add an element to first position use array unshift method.

```js
const add = 1;
const state = [2, 3];

state.pop();
state.unshift(add);

console.log(state);
```